# What music is being played at the beginning of the Third Task and after Cedric and Harry return from the rebirth?

Tags: harry-potter, music-identification

What music is the Hogwarts mini orchestra playing?

Comment: Did Shazam not find it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick look at the [soundtrack listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Goblet_of_Fire_(soundtrack)) indicates that it's the

> ***"Hogwarts March"***.

The song played after Cedric and Harry's return is precisely the same piece of music, albeit interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

it is called "The Hogwarts March" by Patrick Doyle

Comment: The general 'netiquette' for Stack Exchange is to only post an answer if it actually adds information not currently in an existing answer; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3308/20774

Comment: @Valorum, She did add information: she named the composer.

Comment: I agree with @Valorum - this doesn’t add much to his existing answer, which already gives this answer to the question with more detail, like the audio of the song and the title listing from the soundtrack.